# How to integrate splunk with spring cloud sleuth in Spring Boot project?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, splunk, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-sleuth

we are developing microservices using spring boot. we want to track the progress of microservices using Spring Cloud Sleuth and wants to show that logs using Splunk on some dashboard etc.
For demo purpose we have are building three services, Service A calls service B which in turns call Service C. we want to trace their calls using slueth and consolidate them in splunk.
how to implement distributed tracing with Sleuth and Splunk?
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have came across https://github.com/barrycommins/spring-boot-splunk-sleuth-demo , but it is using docker build

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can just add Sleuth to all of your applications and setup a logback encoder that will send logs to Splunk.

Comment: Thanks, @ Marcin Grzejszczak. what i meant was rather than using Zipkin we want to use Splunk and we want to integrate it with our sleuth tracing.

Comment: If there's no way for Splunk to receive traces in a Zipkin format then you have to create your own reporter that will convert from Zipkin to whatever Splunk understands. If you're talking about log correlation then it's exactly what I mentioned a second ago. Just add sleuth and you'll get log correlation out of the box. Your only concern is to send the logs to Splunk.